# How to copy the valid data from one excel to another using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, excel-2007

I am new to selenium web driver, I am trying to execute the login scenario by fetching data from excel_1. Here, I am trying to validate N number of username's and pwd from excel_1 I have succeeded it but I wanna to store only a valid username and pwd in another excel_2. Any idea?..

Answer (score 0):

Write a condition if the login details are valid, then populate the same input string(username and password)in the excel2 or in sheet2

Comment: Hi Ravi, could you please provide syntax for the above scenario because I am confused a lot.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException, InterruptedException

```
{
    File f=new File("C:\\Users\\sravi\\Desktop\\ticket2.xls");
    Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
    Sheet sh=wb.getSheet(0);

    WritableWorkbook wwb=Workbook.createWorkbook(f,wb);
    WritableSheet wsh=wwb.getSheet(0);




        int rows=sh.getRows();
        for(int i=0;i<=rows-1;i++)
        {
            WebDriver obj=new FirefoxDriver();
            obj.get("http:url");

            String uname=sh.getCell(0, i).getContents();
            String pwd=sh.getCell(1, i).getContents();

            obj.findElement(By.name("txtuname")).sendKeys(uname);
            obj.findElement(By.name("txtpswd")).sendKeys(pwd);
            obj.findElement(By.name("btnlogin")).click();

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            String title=obj.getTitle();
            System.out.println(title);

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            if(title.contains("Welcome to Ticket"))      //invalid details
            {
                obj.close();
            }
            else                             //valid login details
            {
                Label l=new Label(2,i,uname);
                wsh.addCell(l);
                Label l1=new Label(3,i,pwd);
                wsh.addCell(l1);
                obj.close();
            }

        }

    wwb.write();
    wwb.close();
    wb.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy data from one excel to another
package ExcelAutomation;

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import jxl.write.Label;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import testBase.PhyWebTestBase;
import utility.PhyWebUtil;

public class CopyExcel extends PhyWebTestBase
{
      public CopyExcel() throws Exception
      {
         super();
      }
      @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Test
      public void CopyFile() throws Exception
      {
           try 
           {
               String srcFilePath = "/Users/raghavendra/Automation/Scripts/4 Weekly Database Changes/Old Databases/887/2015_10_06_Changed_Data_For_Release_887.xlsx";
               String destFilePath = "/Users/raghavendra/Automation/Scripts/4 Weekly Database Changes/Old Databases/887/1 New and Changed Brands,Form or Strength and Manufacturers1.xls";
               String sheetName = "1 New and Changed Brands,Form or Strength and Manufacturers";
               String sheetName1 = "1 New and Changed Brands,Form or Strength and Manufacturers";
               int row = 0;
               String cellValue[][] = new String[10][10];
               XSSFRow rowData1;
               FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(srcFilePath)); 
               XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
               XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);
               sheet=PhyWebUtil.getSheetFromExcel(srcFilePath, 0);
               rowCount=sheet.getLastRowNum();
               rowCount=rowCount+1;
               int colCount = 5;
               XSSFWorkbook workbook1;
               workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook();
               XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.createSheet(sheetName);  
               if(sheetName.indexOf(sheetName1)>-1)
                   colCount=5;
               for(row = 0;row<=rowCount-1;row++)
               {
                   rowData1 = sheet1.createRow(row);
                   for(col=0;col<=colCount;col++)
                   {
                       cellData=sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();
                       rowData1.createCell(col).setCellValue(cellData);
                   }
               }
               inputStream.close();
               FileOutputStream destFile=new FileOutputStream(new File(destFilePath));
               workbook1.write(destFile);
               destFile.flush();
               destFile.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Read_Write {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("path");
      XSSFWorkbook wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
     XSSFSheet  s= wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
     int r = s.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
     for(int i =0;i<r;i++)
     {
         XSSFRow r1= s.getRow(i);
         int c=r1.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
         for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
         {
             XSSFCell c1= r1.getCell(j);
         System.out.print(c1.getStringCellValue()+ "  ");

         }
         System.out.println();
         fs.close();
     }


     FileOutputStream f= new FileOutputStream("path");
     wb.write(f);

}
```

}